# Dedicated Server with Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server with Windows Web 2008 OS. My understanding is that this license doesn't allow to run Hyper-V. Are there other no-cost/low-cost options to creating production capable VPS instances that could run an e-commerce website on this dedicated box such that the IP and access to the e-commerce site is solely to the VPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hyper-V Server](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx) is free, and you can run Windows Web Server 2008 (or any of the other Hyper-V supported Operating Systems as a guest) assuming you have a license to the guest, which it sounds like you do).

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Server 2.0 is free and runs on Windows and Linux.